Celery & Selenium — WebDriverException errors when calling selenium in celery task
I am making a project to scrape a particular website using selenium. When I am running that script normally it's working great but when I am calling it using celery task. It is throwing error
[2024-06-08 11:21:34,119: ERROR/MainProcess] Task taskmanager.tasks.scrape_single_coin[af85f60a-0908-4df4-917d-3051306bcd7f] raised unexpected: WebDriverException()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 453, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 736, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sharm\PycharmProjects\coin_scraper\taskmanager\tasks.py", line 33, in scrape_single_coin
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\sharm\PycharmProjects\coin_scraper\taskmanager\tasks.py", line 25, in scrape_single_coin
    result = scraper.scrape_coin(coin)
  File "C:\Users\sharm\PycharmProjects\coin_scraper\taskmanager\scraper.py", line 22, in scrape_coin
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=self.chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in start
    raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Users\sharm\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win64\125.0.6422.141\chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe


This is the tasks.py file.
from celery import shared_task
from .models import ScrapingTask
import logging
from .scraper import CoinMarketCapScraper

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@shared_task
def scrape_single_coin(job_id, coin):
    scraper = CoinMarketCapScraper()
    try:
        logger.info(f"Starting task for job_id: {job_id}, coin: {coin}")
        result = scraper.scrape_coin(coin)
        task = ScrapingTask.objects.get(job_id=job_id, coin=coin)
        task.status = 'Completed'
        task.result = result
        task.save()
        logger.info(f"Completed task for job_id: {job_id}, coin: {coin}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in task for job_id: {job_id}, coin: {coin} - {e}")
        raise e

I am stuck at this problem for last 2 days and today is deadline to submit this someone please help.
I tried importing the CoinMarketCapScraper class inside the task but no help. It was still throwing error.
